# Pass variable from ajax to jade/pug

Tags: node.js, ajax, pug

Am obtaining the values from nodejs via ajax/fetch and need to pass the same to Pug.
Any help here would be much appreciated

```
sample.pug
      button#searchVal Search
      script(type='text/javascript', src='/lib/onClick.js')
      br
      br
      table#table(div='')
        each row in slaJobs
         tr
          th#cbs-tab-header(div='') !{row.jobname}
          th#cbs-tab-header(div='') !{row.job_type}
          th#cbs-tab-header(div='') !{row.autosys_instance}

dummy.js

    .then(function(data) {
      console.log(data.jobsHeader)
      console.log(data.slaJobs)
       })
```

**Need to set value of data.slaJobs from js to slaJobs of Pug**

Comment: Searched multiple blogs , but no answer i could find for this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**if you can afford to refresh the pug page for the result:**

1. make a request with ajax to some route in node.js.
2. in the route handler - where you render the pug view - you can pass arguments to your view template. 
   so when the pug page will be rendered - It will already contain your data.

**if you can't afford to refresh:**
1. script tag in your template. handle the response and inject the data to the HTML page like any other AJAX

Comment: Thanks for the response , am able to get the new data to the js variable via below script and am stuck here... as like normal HTML i cannot pass the data .. as in Pug am using variable to iterate the value.. so i need pass the value to a Pug variable... not sure if am able to explain

` within JS
    .then(function(data) {
      console.log(data.jobsHeader)
      console.log(data.slaJobs)
 `
Pug vairiable in HTML

`      table#table(div='')
        each row in slaJobs`

Comment: maybe a new route in the node that will get the data from client and render again the same view but with the new data?

Comment: Yes..thanks was just trying it.. but am still not sure how do i pass the new data again to nodejs .. any insights on that will be helpful .. below is the new data which i got in fetch call via js and i can call again diff route.. 

`console.log(data.jobsHeader)`
window.location = "new route"

Comment: Am trying to use a new route... but still not re-rendering,, anything wrong am doing here .. **againclicked** is working but page is not rendering

` First call to prepare data
  fetch('/clicked', { method: 'POST',
                      headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json" } ,
                      body:JSON.stringify({searchKey:searchContent})})

Second call to render new data
 fetch('/againclicked', { method: 'POST', headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json" } , body:JSON.stringify({searchOut:data.slaJobs})})
Both calls are working.but second one again page not rendering

Answer (score 0):

if you are getting data via ajax you should iterate the payload data in a forEach loop and generate HTML into current document. Actually pug is rendered on the server and then the output as HTML will be given to the user.

You can't show your data in your pug view engine while it is already rendered and shown to the user.

a sample:

```
fetch('localhost:3000/products')
   .then(data => data.json())
   .then(data => {
      var div= document.getElementById('div');
      data.forEach(item=>{
          var p = document.createElement('p');
          p.textContent = item[0] + ' ' + item[1];
          div.appendChild(p);
      }
   })
```

Comment: Am trying to use a new route... but still not re-rendering,, anything wrong am doing here .. **againclicked** is working but page is not rendering

` First call to prepare data
  fetch('/clicked', { method: 'POST',
                      headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json" } ,
                      body:JSON.stringify({searchKey:searchContent})})

Second call to render new data
 fetch('/againclicked', { method: 'POST', headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json" } , body:JSON.stringify({searchOut:data.slaJobs})})
Both calls are working.but second one again page not rendering

Comment: I guess your process is basically wrong.. You post data via ajax, is it correct? So then you want to display the data you sent to the server, right? but do you store your data somewhere on server?? if you don't well you get nothing on the second call.

And as I said before pug will only render on full page reload and you can't get the data via ajax call on pug. You should generate your data on client javascript

Comment: Yes.. am doing an Ajax call to get the data and sending the data to server and post process getting the data back via response and all is working fine.. am finding trouble in assigning that data to Pug variable so that data changes in the rendered page. ( it a display and search page )


But however now solved the problem using classic submit button and reloading the page for now.. 

but Ajax would be preferred option.

Comment: @PraveenV So this is what I mean, pug will only render if do complete full load on the server, if want to show your data while getting through ajax call, pug is inaccessible and you need to generate your view in the fetch then block using javascript DOM features, like the example I put above.